# Composer unable to execute command without root

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to use `composer create-project` to generate a new drupal 8 install based on the [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) template.

the documentation for this project recommends the following command:

`composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction`

I know composer should not be run as root (or with sudo) but it fails due to some permission issue or other if run by a normal user who has sudo.

I've tried changing the ownership of the `.composer` folder in my user's home directory. I've tried creating the folder for the project first - it just throws another permission error later in the process.

Suggestions? Composer's documentation explains why it shouldn't be run as root but I can't find any documentation explaining how to use it without sudo...

I am using it with a reasonably vanilla LAMP stack: Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP7.2

The errors when I try to run the above command usually relate to not being able to create files or directories. For example, the `mkdir()` fails when trying to create the project folder.

Comment: Try remove `.composer` directory and make sure that you have write access to directory, where you want to create your project.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get? Permission error could be multiple things.

Comment: Hi, it's hard to answer this clearly without a clear description of what errors you're getting, along with details like where you are trying to create the project, what permissions does that directory have, etc. When you make the directory by hand, do you need `sudo` to do that? At the moment, any answer would be pretty much guesswork.

Comment: It's in ```/var/www/``` so yes I have to use sudo to create the directory. If I do that composer fails with a message that it "cannot delete myDir/". I would like to give more detailed errors but that is all composer is giving me...